# How would I sort out NoneType errors in a for loop?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord

Having issues with trying to pull NoneTypes out of this for loop, just so I don't crash my bot with this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command rank:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Life\discordbot\main.py", line 232, in rank
    await ranking_menu.start(ctx)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\menus\__init__.py", line 967, in start
    await super().start(ctx, channel=channel, wait=wait)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\menus\__init__.py", line 707, in start
    self.message = msg = await self.send_initial_message(ctx, channel)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\menus\__init__.py", line 962, in send_initial_message
    kwargs = await self._get_kwargs_from_page(page)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\menus\__init__.py", line 939, in _get_kwargs_from_page
    value = await discord.utils.maybe_coroutine(self._source.format_page, self, page)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 343, in maybe_coroutine
    return await value
  File "D:\Life\discordbot\main.py", line 207, in format_page
    table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n'
  File "D:\Life\discordbot\main.py", line 207, in <genexpr>
    table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

It would have to be put in this line tho, otherwize the code doesn't work as intended, and i'm having a pain in the butt trying to do that. Any and all help is appreciated!

`table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n' for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))`

Thanks again guys.

iF needed, here is the class it's apart of! and entries is from a returned amount of rows in a database

```
class LocalXpMenu(ListPageSource):
    def __init__(self, ctx, data):
        self.ctx = ctx
        super().__init__(data, per_page = 10)

    async def write_page(self, menu, fields=[]):
         offset = (menu.current_page * self.per_page) + 1
         len_data = len(self.entries)

         embed = Embed(title="Server XP Leaderboard",
                       colour=self.ctx.author.colour)
         embed.set_thumbnail(url = self.ctx.guild.icon_url)
         embed.set_footer(text = f"{offset:,} - {min(len_data, offset+self.per_page-1):,} of {len_data:,} members.")

         for name, value in fields:
             embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)
         return embed

    async def format_page(self, menu, entries):
        fields = []

        table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n'
                for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))

        fields.append(("Ranks", table))

        return await self.write_page(menu, fields)
```

Comment: Where do you call `format_page`? What does `entries` look like?

Comment: entries is a row returned from a database lookup containing

user_id, xp, level

and format page just get's called part of the class here

```    
 #menu
        ranking_menu = MenuPages(source=LocalXpMenu(ctx, xp_ranking))
        await ranking_menu.start(ctx)
```

Comment: So, `entries` is a list of tuples, or something similar? Then `entry` represents the current tuple, and `entry[0]` represents the `user_id`, right? Can you assert that `entry[0]` is an integer, and not something else like a string? `Client.get_user` expects an integer.

Comment: `entry[0]` is a integer correct.

Comment: Then, if that is true for all entries, the only reason `get_user` could be returning `None` is because at least one of the IDs you pass in does not correspond to any existing user - in other words, no user exists with that ID.

Comment: would there be a way to separate that out? And I kinda assumed as much, but I never found a way to implament a way for it to skip, or delete the entry if the id == None

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232747/discussion-between-hunter-and-paul-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways of doing it, but instead of trying to do everything in one line, I think a generator is a nice way to write this. It also filters the entries/users, and skips entries whose user ID does not correspond to an existing user:

```
async def format_page(self, menu, entries):

    def get_table_rows():
        for index, (user_id, xp, level) in enumerate(entries, start=1):
            user = self.ctx.bot.get_user(user_id)
            if user is None:
                # If no user with the current 'user_id' exists, skip it.
                continue
            yield f"{index}. {user.name} (XP: {xp} | Level: {level})\n"

    fields = []

    table = "\n".join(get_table_rows())
    fields.append(("Ranks", table))
    return await self.write_page(menu, fields)
```

Comment: Thanks dude! So how does a generator really work? I think I remember hearing that it counts each time it's run? I could be 100% wrong here/

Comment: Think of a generator as being like a function but with state. A generator "yields" a single item at a time to the calling code, until the generator is exhausted and there are no more items left to yield. Each time an item is yielded, execution of the generator is paused until the next item is requested. The `"\n".join(get_table_rows())` consumes all items from the generator.

Comment: OH! I watched a video on it but it didn't just click until now, that's pretty interesting, thank you very much for all the help dude!